# ServiceStack.CacheAccess.Memcached broken with latest NuGet Update

Tags: c#, memcached, servicestack

A new set of NuGet packages for the core service stack libraries was released last night and since I upgraded I have been getting errors in the ServiceStack.CacheAccess.Memcached library which was not part of the update.

```
Compilation failed: 3 error(s), 0 warnings

.../App_Start/AppHost.cs(90,62): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `MemcachedClientCache' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
.../App_Start/AppHost.cs(90,35): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `Funq.Container.Register<ServiceStack.CacheAccess.ICacheClient>(ServiceStack.CacheAccess.ICacheClient)' has some invalid arguments
.../packages/ServiceStack.3.9.56/lib/net35/ServiceStack.dll (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
.../App_Start/AppHost.cs(90,35): error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert `object' expression to type `ServiceStack.CacheAccess.ICacheClient'
```

Any ideas as I have not removed or added any references, just upgraded the core packages that came in the nuget feed.